# Issue with stateful date and time on reservation app using useState and useReducer (solved)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I'm having an issue with a reservation app where available times are randomly generated for each date and when a user books that particular date/time it should not show as available anymore. Everything pretty much appears as expected at first except when changing the date more than once all the times disappear from the list. Here is some of the relevant code from the BookingForm component:

```
const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [date,setDate] = useState("");
    const [time,setTime] = useState("");
    const [numGuests, setNumGuests] = useState("2");
    const [occasion, setOccasion] = useState("");
    const [finalTimes, setFinalTimes] = useState(
        availableTimes.map((aTime) => {
            return <option>{aTime}</option> 
        }))

    function handleDateChange(e) { 
        setDate(e.target.value);

        let stringDate = e.target.value;
        let chosenDate = new Date(stringDate);

        setAvailableTimes(chosenDate);

        setFinalTimes(availableTimes.map((aTime) => {
            return <option>{aTime}</option> 
        }));
    }
```

and from the parent component:

```
const updateTimes = (date) => {
        return fetchAPI(date);
    }

    const initializeTimes = fetchAPI(new Date());
    
    const [availableTimes, dispatch] = useReducer(updateTimes,initializeTimes);

    return (
        <>
        <BookingForm availableTimes={availableTimes} setAvailableTimes={dispatch}/>
        </>
    )
```

can provide more detail if necessary. the fetchAPI component was not written by me but I can include that code if it helps. Thanks

I'm honestly stuck, maybe a fresh set of eyes could help me out.

Update- issue was with the "updateTimes" API call in the parent component. I forgot to send the date as a Date() object to the API when updating the date. Below is the fixed function.

```
    const updateTimes = (date) => {
           return fetchAPI(Date(date));
        }
```